# C++: How to recognize that your program was started from Visual Studio, not from OS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Having the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // program code
  std::cout << std::endl << "Press <ENTER> to exit..." << std::endl;
  std::getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

When I start this program from Visual Studio it writes:

```
"Press <ENTER> to exit..."
```

waits for ENTER key pressed, than writes Visual Studio standard:

```
"Press any key to continue..."
```

Therefore, from Visual Studio (Ctrl+F5) I need to press buttons two times, but only one is desired.

How can I workaround this issue (some code that detects start from Visual Studio and allows to "comment" my "key press waiting code")?

Thanks

Comment: I would compare the environment variables seen by the program between the two different cases.  I would expect there is some reliable indication, but would not be surprised if there is not.

Comment: You can comment your code independent of how it is executed; use `/* C syntax */` or `// C++ syntax` for making comments.

Comment: what if instead of Ctrl+F5, you just run your application with F5?

Comment: @KerrekSB What do you mean? Cannot find logic between comments styles and my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up your project settings so that Visual Studio passes a command line argument to your program every time it starts up. So, just make a command line argument which tells it not to pause on exit, and set up Visual Studio to pass that argument.

If you've never worked with command line arguments before, they show up in `argc`/`argv` in your `main`.

Comment: It would seem that adding a "/nopause" argument would be a generally useful addition to the program anyway (to allow the program to be used in scripts, etc, as described by @David Schwartz)

Answer (score 3):

Just get rid of the "press enter to exit" code and exit. That's a pointless thing to do and makes it more difficult to use your program in scripts or as a filter. It's much better that you never develop that bad habit then develop it and have to break it.

Comment: it's pointless to have that code when the program is used in scripts or as a filter, or anywhere else for that matter.  However, this is a very common practice to have while writing or debugging the said program because when you run the process under visual studio debugger, as soon as the process terminates, command window is closed so you miss any output that may have been reported.  That's why you want the code OP has during development.  His question specifically asked how do I activate during debugging, but skip it for all other invocations.

Comment: @DXM Read the question carefully. The OP is trying to do exactly the opposite of what you are saying. He wants to *disable* his "press enter to continue" from a debugging environment.

Comment: oh yeah, that's kinda weird then. I'll just remove my answer and give you +1 in that case.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz +1 thanks. There is requirement in my case. Double key press annoyed me and this question raised.

Comment: So get rid of the code that waits for a keypress and the double keypress wiil go away.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz get rid for develop time only. In final version I need to make it possible for the user to watch the results. This is the requirement.

Comment: @DaddyM You're writing a console program, not a GUI program, right? If the user launches the program from a console, they can see the results when the program exits.

Comment: If he says it's a requirement, why are you pushing him? Maybe the users launch it from a double-click on the EXE in Explorer. Maybe the program makes no sense as a filter.

Comment: @StilesCrisis If someone says, "How can I use a jackhammer to get the demons out of my grandmother's head?" should I explain to him how to use a jackhammer? You don't help people by assuming the rarest possible case.

Comment: I guess the idea that the program is a text filter just doesn't seem like what's actually happening here. This appears to be a program that includes a user interaction component (especially given that the OP desires the press-a-key-to-quit functionality when not debugging). We're not always trying to interact with Unix shell scripts.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Stop pushing me :))) Liked joke about jackhammer. People who will use this program will you it from "double-click" as StileCrisis said. User are extremely not professional. it's probably bad and inconvenient but it is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few ways to do this. One would be to have Visual Studio pass a command line flag to the program when you launch it in the debugger (Project Properties->Debug->Command Line Arguments).

Another trick would be to probe for whether a debugger is attached. There [good sample code at Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1492/Is-The-Debugger-Attached) for that.

Comment: `IsDebuggerXXX()` is useful only when debug (F5). Ctrl+F5 does not launch debugger. So this method will not work.